# The onsubmit function in react form makes the console to clear and refresh

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, console.log

The onsubmit function in react form forces the console to clear and refresh, thus making it impossible for me to see the logs and analyze them.

I want to log some words on my console after the submit button in my form gets clicked.
but as soon as the button is clicked, the console is refreshed and I can only see the log for a slight moment.

here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
    type === "checkbox" ? this.setState({ [name]: checked }) : this.setState({ [name]: value })
    console.log("changed");
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log("submited");
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <div className="container">
          <label htmlFor="username"><b>Username</b></label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.username}
            placeholder="Enter Username" 
            name="username" 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            required>
          </input>

          <label htmlFor="password"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            value={this.state.password}
            placeholder="Enter Password" 
            name="password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}  
            required>
          </input>

          <button>Login</button>

        </div>

      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause the form is doing is native way of submitting the form which is a normal page refresh or action to the form url. You can
use
`e.preventDefault()`

to prevent that

Something along like

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submited");
  }
```

To defer the submission

Answer (score 3):

See bro! `form` has native default behavior to be refresh once you hit enter to submit it. Thus we can prevent this native behavior of form by including this simple 1 LOC:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Qn arises? Where to include it line of code (LOC)
ans:In your `handleSubmit` method, pass in the event argument, and add this in the beginning.

something like this:-

```
handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("submited");
}
```