# Render a button[type="submit"] in a form trigger the onSubmit callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

With a `edit` boolean state, I conditionally render a button of type `"submit"` inside a `form` element. However as you can see when I set `edit` to `true` and render the button, the `onSubmit` callback of the `form` is triggered:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={() => console.log("submit")}>
        {edit ? (
          <button type="submit">send</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>edit</button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nervous-nightingale-07hqy]

This doesn't happen if I use an `input` instead of the `button`:

```html
<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: This isn't really related to react/javascript, i suggest working with a sample that doesn't include them.

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is all explained in the docs for buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Mmh I think it could be really usefull for people that face this problem with React :/

Comment: All react does here is swap one element for another, what happens with each button that's there is standard. Buttons without a type are type submit, when you click a submit button, the form submits.

Comment: Set the button type to `button` the default is `submit`

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125079/the-onsubmit-function-in-react-form-makes-the-console-to-clear-and-refresh

Comment: Oh thanks for the explanation so it's not because of the re-render but because of the first button click. You can add an answer if you want or I could just delete this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for others who might find it helpful.

This could also be the React virtual DOM not realizing it is a different button while the event is propagating through, and passing the reference that was to the "edit" button to the new "send" button and rendering it in place while the effect of the button click on edit button still propagating, therefore effectively, submitting when it hits the form.

Others have recommending stopping propagation, which will work, but it requires catching the event manually.  Another option is to add a react "key" to each button. That way React knows that the 'send' button is truly a new element.

To update the OPs example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={() => console.log("submit")}>
        {edit ? (
          <button 
            key='sendButton' 
            type="submit"
          >
            send
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button 
            key='editButton' 
            onClick={() => setEdit(true)}
          >
            edit
          </button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this to prevent from default submit on re-rendering

```
export default function App() {
const [edit, setEdit] = React.useState(false);

return (
<div className="App">
  <form
    onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("submit");
    }}
  >
    {edit ? (
      <button type="submit">send</button>
    ) : (
      <button onClick={() => setEdit(true)}>edit</button>
    )}
  </form>
 </div>
 );
}
```